# Unhandled exception error in Coin3D ( Open Inventor )

Tags: c++, openinventor

I wanted to make a general function that would search for a class type in a node and returns its address. It is defined below

```
SoNode* searchandgive(SoType searchtype, SoNode* searchnode)
{
    SoSearchAction mysearch;
    mysearch.setType(searchtype);
    mysearch.setInterest(SoSearchAction::FIRST);
    mysearch.apply(searchnode);
    if (mysearch.getPath() == NULL) { 

        std::cout<<"No property of this type was found";
    }

    SoPath* mypath=mysearch.getPath();
    return mypath->getTail();
}
```

But when I pass a search type like SoCoordinate3::getClassTypeId() and the node to be searched for senode as given below:

```
 SoCoordinate3 * mycoords=(SoCoordinate3*) searchandgive(SoCoordinate3::getClassTypeId(),senode);
 const SbVec3f *s=mycoords->point.getValues(0);
 std::cout<<"   " <<s->getValue()[25];  // Some point
```

But the last line is generating a Unhandled Exception Error. Please tell what am I doing wrong here. The last line is valid since the same written inside the scope of the function works but not here.

Comment: Why didn't you check null pointers return?

Answer (score 0):

With this you are standing that `mysearch.getPath()` could be null:

```
if (mysearch.getPath() == NULL) { 

        std::cout<<"No property of this type was found";
    }
```

but below you are using that without any check:

```
SoPath* mypath=mysearch.getPath();
    return mypath->getTail();
```

so this can raise an Unhandled Exception.

Another poitn is the line:

```
std::cout<<"   " <<s->getValue()[25];  // Some point
```

There is no check about how many points are in the vector, and this as well could cause an exception.

Comment: I have made the code shorter just for posting. And if we do not consider the worst case scenario, i.e. a SoCoordinate3 is found then what's the explanation. I have tried the code inside the scope of searchandgive function and it works fine. Moreover the address mypath.getTail() is pointing is also the same as what mycoords is pointing to.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Felice. But it is alredy known to me that getValue[25] exists and I have even tried the same inside the function scope and got the correct answer, but not from outside the scope of the function. I am importing an stl using the SoSTLFileKit class.